# Use default permalink for custom post (and no slug)

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, taxonomy, slug

I'v created a custom post type with this code :

```
register_post_type('Villes',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __('Villes'),
            'singular_name' => __('Villes'),
        ),            
        'public'      => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite'     => array('slug' => 'villes'),
        'taxonomies'  => array( 'category' ) 
    )
);
```

As you've noticed I've activated Categories for the post. This is the structure on my categories :

- cat1

  - sub1
  - sub2
- cat2

I've created a custom post in the **sub2** category, what should I do so the permalink of the post is mysite.com/**cat1/sub2**/post-slug (and not mysite.com/**villes**/post-slug)

Comment: IIRC /%category%/%postname%/ include subcategory. for instance,  parent_cat/child_cat/title

Comment: The rule you gave works only for posts, not for a custom post ! i.e. if "post-slug" was a simple post the url'll be /parent_cat/child_cat/title, but in my case it's /custom-slug/title !